# How to retain an hyperlink in Google sheet referenced data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Part of the text in a Google Sheet cell (A1) is hyperlinked.  For example, say A1 is:

This is a [Google Sheet](https://www.google.com)

Now say that A1 is referenced elsewhere.  For example, say B1's value is `=A1`.  The problem is that B1 only displays the visible text of A1.  The hyperlinking in A1 is not retained in B1.  In other words, B1 displays as:

This is a Google Sheet

How can I ensure that the referenced cell shows the hyperlink as well?

The crucial point seems to be that not all of A1 is a hyperlink; only *some* of the text is a hyperlink.  If A1 were hyperlinked in its entirety then B1 is correctly hyperlinked as well.

I have a [simple example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KG8-qSIX92ZjOcbKy9t2q1H5wmUsZn6GAwiMsBT8Wjc/edit?usp=sharing) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) does not seem to work either. But, instead of not showing the hyperlink, it shows the entire cell as an hyperlink, lol.

Comment: According to [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/142996/257514) answer, this is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Mario, currently it appears the Google Apps Script solution is the only workaround.  To build upon his work, consider also adding an if-check in the function so that apps script only copies A1 to B1 if A1 was the cell that was edited:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  console.log(e)
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (e.range.columnStart === 1
    && e.range.columnEnd === 1
    && e.range.rowEnd === 1
    && e.range.rowStart === 1) {
    sh.getRange('A1').copyTo(sh.getRange('B1'));
  }
}
```

You can console.log the event to see all the data available for interrogation when the onEdit trigger executes.

The if-check reduces the overhead by only making a second call to google sheets if A1 was indeed the cell of edit. Great workaround Mario!

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.  That gets me going.  Now I need to make it generic.  It won't always be `A1 -> B1`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible based also on this [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/83073/is-it-possible-to-have-plain-text-and-a-link-in-the-same-cell/142996#142996) using a google sheets formula.

But if you are open to workarounds and google apps script, then this very simple script will copy the value and it will reserve the text `url`:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange('A2').copyTo(sh.getRange('B2'));
}
```

You can also create an `onEdit` trigger to automatically copy the formula upon edits.

Excuse me in advance if this wasn't the direction you were looking for.